# Invoking element directive from controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I have an element `directive` that i need to invoke from a `controller`,rather than writing that in html file.

**Element Directive:**

```
angular.module("providerApp")
         .directive("openTab", function () {
         return {
             restrict: 'E',
             templateUrl: '/resources/js/directiveView/openTab.html'
         }
     });
```

This `directive` i want to invoke through my controller in `script`,rather than writing in html file.
Something like this:

**Controller**

```
angular.module("providerApp")
    .controller('appointmentsController', function() {
        $("<div>").append("<open-Tab></open-Tab>");
});
```

Rather than writing in `html` file as written below.I want to skip writing directive in markUp as it has to be rendered dynamically and its place in dom is not fixed,which is determined by `controller`.

**MarkUp**

```
 <html>
       <head></head>
       <body>
          <open-tab></open-tab>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will also work, just you need to use `$compile` service to compile DOM before adding it to DOM, but it is considered as bad pattern in AngularJS.

> Doing DOM manipulation from controller considered as bad practice in
>   Angular

Better you create your own directive which will be on body level. The controller which want to add an element, It will `$emit` and event to upward with `selector` & `html`. So that the directive will add that element inside DOM.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('appointmentsController', function($scope) {
  $scope.$emit('ElementAppend', {
    selector: '#test',
    html: '<open-Tab></open-Tab>'
  });
});
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('body', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    compile: function(element, attributes) {
      return {
        pre: function(scope, element, attributes) {
          scope.$on('ElementAppend', function(e, data) {
            $(element).find(data.selector).append($compile(data.html)(scope));
          });
        }
      }
    },
  }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/eCThUqWYqLzgU9tUsTzg?p=preview)

Comment: As i asked, i dont want to invoke my directive from markUp. Basically Directive's position in markUp is determined by controller, so it has to be dynamically rendered from controller.

Comment: @GyaneshGouraw did you checked it.?